# Surjectivity of a map on inverse limits

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, modules, limits-and-colimits

(The following is crossposted from [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759503/surjectivity-of-a-map-on-inverse-limits), where the question did not receive any answers.)

I am looking for a proof of the following lemma from P. Gabriel's *Des catégories abéliennes* (Chap. IV, §3, Lemme 1):

> **Lemma.** Let $B$ be a ring, $(I, \leq)$ be a directed poset, and $(M_i, f_{ji}:M_j\rightarrow M_i)_{j\geq i},$ $(N_i, g_{ji}:N_j\rightarrow N_i)_{j\geq i}$ two inverse systems of $B$-modules. Let $(h_i: M_i\rightarrow N_i)_i$ be a morphism of the inverse systems, and assume that all the maps $h_i$ are surjective with an Artinian kernel. Then the limit map
>   $$\varprojlim_i h_i: \varprojlim_i M_i\rightarrow \varprojlim_i N_i$$ is surjective.

I am looking either for a proof (I haven't manage to come up with one so far), or for a reference to a proof - Gabriel refers to "Bourbaki, *Topologie*, I Appendice, $3^{\text{e}}$ éd.", which is a reference I cannot find anywhere.

I do not want to assume that e.g. $I$ is countable - the reason is that I need this lemma, similarly as Gabriel in his thesis, to establish some properties of pseudo-compact modules over a pseudo-compact ring (namely that quotient of a pseudo-compact module by a closed submodule is pseudo-compact, and exactness of inverse limits). For this reason, as far as I can tell, I cannot use countable index sets (i.e. countable bases of neighbourhoods) in general.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I apologize for the late reaction, I dived into the references you provided but I struggle with French so it takes me longer. Thank you for your help, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question can be interpreted as the vanishing of the first derived projective limit functor ${\lim\limits_{\leftarrow}}^{(1)} \mathcal M$ for the projective spectrum of the kernels. If these kernels are Artenian even all derivatives vanish. This is shown in Corollary 7.2 of C.U. Jensen's *Les Foncteurs Dérivés de lim  et leurs Applications en Théorie des Modules*, Springer Lecture Notes 254 (1972). He also refers to his article *On the vanishing of* ${\lim\limits_{\leftarrow}}^{(i)}$, J. Algebra 15 (1970), 151-166 (but I did not have a look at it).

It seems to me that Jensen does not claim for originality as he writes "Il est bien connu...". However, he does not give an explicit reference. A main step in his proof is a result in Bourbaki's *Topologie Générale*.

Comment: Am I missing something? The result in Bourbaki's book requires a numerable subset, however, I can't see why this is true in his arguments.

Comment: In the result quoted from Jensen's Lecture Notes countability is not required.

Comment: That's the point, my version says that the index set has a numerable subset. Can you show me the quoted result directly? Mine is: Theorem 1 (Mittag-Leffler)- Let (X_{\alpha,f_{\alpha,\beta}})  be a projective system of uniform, complete and separated spaces, indexed by a filtered set $I$ which admits a numerable cofinal subset; we suppose in addition that for any $\alpha\in I$, $X_{\alpha}$ possesses a numerable fundamental system of entourages.

Comment: This is Bourbaki, in fact originally due to Arens, about spectra of complete metric spaces. This definitely needs some countability for the index set. Jensen's theorem has a certain form of compactness in its assumptions. That's why (I believe) he does not need countability.

Comment: I mean the reference is still not correct. I find a probably right reference which uses set theory and no countability is needed. The reference is Bourbaki Theorie des Ensembles, page 162, Theorem 1. Anyway, I'll check the details.