# Conditions for exact projective limits for some Mittag-Leffler systems?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, limits-and-colimits

Let $(M_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(N_i)_{i\in I}$ be Mittag-Leffler systems of $R$-modules. I have a map $(h_i)$ of projective systems such that every $h_i$ is surjective. I search for conditions for $\lim \limits_{\leftarrow} M_i \rightarrow \lim \limits_{\leftarrow} N_i$ to be surjective.

I am in a complicated case (from my point of vue) being the following :

- the systems have no reasons to be countable, nor totally ordered.
- I tried to follow de IV, §3 of "Categories abéliennes" of P. Gabriel, in SMF. However my ring $R$ is a $R_0$-toplogical algebra, complete and separated but not pseudo-compact (even if $R_0$ is a pseudo compact ring). $R$ itself is not pseudo compact. I tried to raffine the conditions of Gabriel replacing the finite length conditions by artinian conditions. But even this does not work : $R$ has no base of neighborhood $R'$ such that $R/R'$ are artinian as $R_0$-modules (otherwise I would have won).

Cool points :

- My modules are of finite type.
- To be precise $R_0=k[[ X_0, \ldots, X_n ]]$ and $R=R_0 [X_i^{-1}]$ for several variables.
- The modules I look after also have additionnal structures that I may exploit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this is just an announcement for a talk, without slides or links to a paper. You should perhaps ask Andrea Pulita, he is on Math Overflow but one cannot tag people here.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks !

Comment: You can tell him that I suggested you to ask him. We know quite well each other.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following on the web — I have no idea whether it will be helpful, but try to have a look.

https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/34846

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the *derived limit functor* ${\lim\limits_\leftarrow}^1$ to vanish on the system of the kernels $H_i$ of the morphisms $h_i$. A reference is given in this MO answer
[Surjectivity of a map on inverse limits](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301373/surjectivity-of-a-map-on-inverse-limits/301433#301433)

Comment: As far as I understand in the situation considered above by Nataniel the Artinian assumption is not fulfilled.

Comment: Yes, I thought at first of the theorem by Gabriel, but was not able to fulfuill the artinian assumption ( $k[[X,Y]][(XY)^{-1}]/k[[X,Y]]$ is not artinian over $k[[X,Y]]$).